# TypeError: openlog() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, logging, syslog

I am trying to write to syslog in one of my scripts. Here is the code for logger.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import syslog
import urllib
import datetime

def log(msg, level="info"):
    msg = safe(msg)
    if os.environ.get('debug'):
        debugmsg = "{0} {1}".format(datetime.datetime.now(), msg)
        print(debugmsg, file=sys.stderr)
    syslog.openlog(ident=__file__,logoption=syslog.LOG_PID,facility=syslog.LOG_LOCAL0)
    syslog.syslog(level, msg)

def safe(str):
    return urllib.unquote_plus(str)
```

When I go to test the log function via `logger.log("Hello world!")`, the interpreter throws `TypeError: openlog() takes no keyword arguments`.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem with an older version of python. See [this](http://www.meetup.com/phillypug/messages/58287772/) and [that](https://github.com/ifke/smonitor/issues/1)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, I am running this under Python 2.6.6, so its possible that may be the issue. I am still not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: You can drop the keyword arg usage in favor of positional. They already are in the right order.

Comment: That fixed my issue.